# Extra factors appear when evaluating Euler integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, special-functions, version-8

**Note: this is fixed in version 9.**

---

When I perform the double integral in *Mathematica*,

```
Integrate[(x (1 - x))^z (y (1 - y))^z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

which should give

$$B(z+1,z+1)^2 = \frac{\Gamma(z+1)^4}{\Gamma\left(2(z+1)\right)^2}$$

where $B(x,y)$ is the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and $\Gamma(z)$ is the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) because the integral is a product of two Beta functions, I instead get this ratio of Gamma functions *times the extra factor $(-1)^{2z}$*. What is going on here? To make matters stranger, if I do the integral instead using two nested calls to Integrate (one to integrate out $x$ and one to integrate out $y$), I get the ratio of Gamma functions without the incorrect extra factor.

Comment: After playing around and breaking the problem up, it looks like a legitimate issue with Integrate. Send the example in to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Are you sure about the validity of the expression you gave over the *entire* complex plane? It seems that the $ (-1)^{2z} $ factor comes from a resultant of the Gammas.

Comment: @gpap, that's not the issue: try running `Assuming[Re[z]>0 && Im[z]==0, Integrate[(x (1 - x))^z (y (1 - y))^z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`. $(-1)^{2z}$ should definitely not be there.

Comment: Definitely a bug. Hoping the fix creates no trouble of its own.

Comment: @Mike Please post that as an answer and accept when the system lets you (so the question doesn't appear unanswered).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram Research has confirmed that this is a bug. From an email I just received: *Integrate does appear to be giving an incorrect result, and I have forwarded the example to our developers.*

Comment: They always say the same about `Integrate`. Look e.g. here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8161/mathematica-gives-wrong-answer-for-integral and here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/bug-in-integrate-for-mathematica and read the comments here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353441/can-you-explain-this-mathematica-assumptions-behaviour

Comment: @Artes Yes, it's quite annoying that they just wave you off with the statement that Integrate is buggy rather than giving a general sense of the reasons why it might not be working so this could at least be avoided in the future.