# different values of integral with/without bogus assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, convolution

I do not understand why I get different answers for the following two identical integrals.

```
Integrate[Cos[10*Pi (z - x)], {x, 1/10, 1}, Assumptions :> {}]
Integrate[Cos[10*Pi (z - x)], {x, 1/10, 1}, Assumptions :> {x > 0}]
```

Output (respectively):

```
-Sin[10Pi*z]/5Pi
Sin[10Pi*z]/5Pi
```

Running version 9.  Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I get the same output for each line from version 10.0.0 under Windows.  What version are you running and what output do you get?

Comment: What did you get? I've checked results im _Mathematica_ versions _7_ and _10_; they were the same however in version _8_ the results were different by the sign (a bug).

Comment: Updated question- have similar sign issue in 9.0.0. So (-) is correct?

Comment: There were certain problems in _ver. 8_ with `Integrate`, they have been fixed though not all, see e.g. [Mathematica gives wrong answer for an integral](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8161/mathematica-gives-wrong-answer-for-an-integral), in _ver. 9_:  [Mathematica 9 can't integrate this function but earlier versions could](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26926/mathematica-9-cant-integrate-this-function-but-earlier-versions-could) or [Bug in analytic integration?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48113/bug-in-mathematica-analytic-integration)

Comment: This is a trivial excersise, so you shouldn't ask, just verify it!